# Meaning of perfect setups

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following context is given:

> When Jerry Wagner and Kevin Moonan came out of the bar they were
>   ***perfect setups***.

What does the phrase I emphasized mean?

Comment: Add the context. *Setup* has a couple of meanings. If we forcefully fit, both the meanings look fine here.

Comment: As mentioned more context is needed, but my guess would be [setup](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/setup) sense 4d, "a person who is easily tricked". "Perfect" basically means ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm right, your sentence is out of "The Godfather" by Mario Puzo.

> The two big men were getting out of the car. They were both ex-boxers
> who had never made it past the small clubs and had been fixed up by
> Sonny Corleone with a little loan-shark action so that they could make
> a decent living. They were, naturally, anxious to show their
> gratitude.
>
> When Jerry Wagner and Kevin Moonan came out of the bar they were
> perfect setups. The bar girl's taunts had left their adolescent vanity
> prickly. Paulie Gatto, leaning against the fender of his car, called
> out to them with a teasing laugh, Hey, Casanova, those broads really
> brushed you off.
>
> The two young men turned on him with delight. Paulie Gatto looked like
> a perfect outlet for their humiliation. Ferret-faced, short, slightly
> built and a wise guy in the bargain. They pounced on him eagerly and
> immediately found their arms pinned by two men grabbing them from
> behind. At the same moment Paulie Gatto had slipped onto his right
> hand a specially made set of brass knuckles studded with
> one-sixteenth-inch iron spikes. His timing was good, he worked out in
> the gym three times a week. He smashed the punk named Wagner right on
> the nose. The man holding Wagner lifted him up off the ground and
> Paulie swung his arm, uppercutting into the perfectly positioned
> groin. Wagner went limp and the big man dropped him. This had taken no
> more than six seconds.

In that case, setup has the following meaning:

> a scheme or trick intended to incriminate or deceive someone.
>
> *"Listen. He didn't die. It was a setup.”*
>
> synonyms: trick, trap;
> conspiracy; informal put-up job, frame-up
>
> Source: [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=setups)

The ***perfect setups***, in the given sentence, implies that Jerry and Kevin were in just the right spot/place/situation to be tricked into the trap placed by Paulie Gatto.